# Get the Number of line in XML doc using vb.net and xElement

Tags: xml, vb.net, numbers, line, xelement

I need to retrieve the line and col number of an xml document when I'm parsing it on vb.net;
here is an example:

xml:

```xml
<?xml version = "1,0"encoding = "utf-8"?>        <!-- line 1 -->

 <user>                                          <!-- line 2 -->
        <name>dave</name>                        <!-- line 3 -->
        <age>29</age>                            <!-- line 4 -->
        <function>medic</function>               <!-- line 5 --><!-- col 8  -->
 </user>                                         <!-- line 6 -->
```

vb:

```vb
Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.load(xmlDocName) 
'xmlDocName is the path of the document'

Dim nodes = from data in xelement.elements("user")
for each xEle in nodes
        name = xEle.Elements.("name").value.toString
        age  = xEle.Elements.("age").value.toString
        func = xEle.Elements.("function").value.toString

        if func = string.empty then
        'Here is my problem:'
        'I need some thing like that:'
            line = xEle.Elements.("age").lineNumber.toString
            'the variable line should receve the value '5''
             col = xEle.Elements.("age").colNumber.toString
            'the variable col should receve the value '8''

          'But those methods does not exist...'
        end if
next
```

I need an help using the `XElement` class, if it is not possible I will have to change it.

Comment: When working with DOM all underlying details are lost. AFAIK for such task you should resort a lower level (and old) `XmlTextReader` (where you have `LineNumber` and `LinePosition` properties for current parsed element). Of course such nice things as a `For Each` over nodes selected by a XPath expression won't be available there...

Answer (score 0):

I Found a way to get the line number, it is working but I do not know if it is the best way
to solve my problem. Also I have to test the performace for using this code in big documents and to process a great deal of xmls.

```
vb:

Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.load(xmlDocName,LoadOptions.SetLineInfo) 
'xmlDocName is the path of the document'  
Dim nodes = from data in  xelement.elements("user")
for each xEle in nodes
      name = xEle.Elements.("name").value.toString
      age  = xEle.Elements.("age").value.toString
      func = xEle.Elements.("function").value.toString

      if func = string.empty then
          Dim nodes2 = from data in xelement.elements("user").elements("function")
          Dim info As IXmlLineInfo = nodes2.first
          line = info.LineNumber
      end if
next
```